# Seemingly random error when writing to /tmp

Tags: files

Lately I've been getting numerous errors of this type:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#
```

Yet the `/tmp` directory is set to 777.

Oddly enough: If I try to reload the page several times the error does not occur.

Comment: Go to configuration and check tmp path is /tmp

Comment: Check you have enough disk space on the /tmp disk. May be some combination of queries consume all avaialble disk, so you see that message, and after that some space is freed and you don't see the message.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, if you just be a problem of space.

Comment: As regards the randomness, this error is being issued by the DB (so in passing the temp space configured for Drupal is irrelevant to this error), which suggests that the reason you don't get it every time is that on those occasions the query result has been cached by the server and it is in memory.